# Google Compute Engine - DSpace stops working when I turn on the instance

Tags: tomcat, google-compute-engine, tomcat8

A few months ago I installed DSpace (an open source repository that uses tomcat) on a Google virtual machine. A few weeks ago I paused the instance and now that I re-enabled it it doesn't open. I don't even know why the external IP changed, however with the new link (http://35.192.9.69/xmlui/) it doesn't open either. This is what appears

[ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3rCt.png)

Things I have tried: - Delete my GoogleChrome history - Try with safari, chrome and firefox. iOS and Windows - Delete my DNS - Pause and start the instance - Restart tomcat8 from the console

I attach the status of tomcat according to what appears in the console

[tomcat status output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgyaG.png)

I am desperate, and I don't know what I can do, there was all of the work we have done in months, any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the tomcat daemon is working. Is possible that the Firewall rules are blocking your instance external IP since the IP address has been changed. (go to VPC network> Firewall rules)

Also, I would recommend you to get a Static IP address [1] rather than a dynamic IP.
[1]https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address
I hope this helps you to solve your issue.